# How to get bitmap from imageView

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I need to take an image from imageView and make it as a bitmap.

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("ImageUri");
mImageViewFilter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewFilter);
Glide.with(this)
          .load(s)
          .into(mImageViewFilter);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mImageViewFilter.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

You can see that into mImageViewFilter I am loading a photo with use of its URI and Glide library.
My next step is to take this photo which is in mImageViewFilter and make it as a bitmap. After the last line of code there is an exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exception are you encountering?

Answer (score 6):

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("ImageUri");
mImageViewFilter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewFilter);
```

To load image into ImageView use below code

```
Glide.with(this).load(s).into(mImageViewFilter);
```

So in order to get bitmap from ImageView (mImageViewFilter )

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

**OR**

You can add this before the code where you are trying to get Bitmap out of the ImageView

```
mImageViewFilter.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

In order to get the Bitmap out of the ImageView using DrawingCache, you first need to enable ImageView to draw image cache.

```
Bitmap bitmap = mImageViewFilter.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you doing right thing. But the problem is Image loading is Asynchronous call.
And you called `getBitmap()` in right next line which will be called sequentially.
And it will give you null anyway cause image is not loaded yet .

**Solution**
if you want to do it in next direct step .You can use direct `Bitmap` callback.

```
Glide.with(this)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(path)
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
           // Use resource as bitmap save it for later.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward way to obtain a bitmap from any `View` including `ImageView` is to get the drawing cache from it.

```
mImageViewFilter.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = mImageViewFilter.getDrawingCache();
```

But the above method may give you a low quality image.

I think you should directly decode the bitmap from the `Uri` using `BitmapFactory`

```
InputStream in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
in.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

First take it as bitmap, then take it again to apply to our ImageView :

```
Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(this) //taking as bitmap
    .load(s)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(100, 100) //width and height
    .get();
Glide.with(this) //apply to imageview
      .load(s)
      .into(mImageViewFilter);
```